# Converting docx to Base64 using contentResolver gives unreadable format on Android

Tags: android, kotlin, android-contentresolver

I have a file **test.docx** containing 1 word "Testing". This file is on my dropbox folder and I open this from within the App using contentResolver.

[image]

Code:

```
            val inputStream = context.contentResolver.openInputStream(uri)
            val allText = inputStream.bufferedReader().use(BufferedReader::readText)
            base64Image = Base64.encodeToString(allText.toByteArray(), Base64.NO_WRAP)
```

the allText gives back some data but when putting this in textfile and saving it as .docx I cannot view it, it's broken. I think I should add a Charset to the bufferedReader method. Tried a couple but none of them work.

What should be the correct code for this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`DOCX` is not plain text. It is a binary format. Use [`readBytes()`](https://kotlinlang.org/api/latest/jvm/stdlib/kotlin.io/java.io.-input-stream/read-bytes.html) to read in the bytes:

```
val bytes = context.contentResolver.openInputStream(uri).readBytes()
```

Bear in mind that your app will crash with an `OutOfMemoryError` for large content. Please reconsider your plan to read in the entire content, let alone convert it to base64.